# BrowserSync: don't work external link

Tags: networking, browser-sync

I use BrowserSync for development. However, I'm having a problem.

[image: Screenshot]

I can open a site from a computer on both links. But to view the site from the phone, by opening an external link, it just does not load. The project and the browser are located on the Ubuntu on Windows. I do not understand the network well. Perhaps something blocks access from an external source, but I do not know how to determine this.

Comment: External is not your public IP but internal. You have to Port forward from router to local IP to be able to access from phone network

Comment: If phone is on WiFi and still does not work, try to allow Port 3000 in the firewall

Comment: I determined the reason. This is the Avast firewall. I opened the 3000 port in the Windows firewall and turned off the Avast firewall and it all worked. When I turn on the firewall Avast nothing is loaded. And how to open a port in Avast I have no idea. And Google also ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯

Comment: I think you should add the application as an exception in Avast instead of trying to mod Avast firewall or anything

Answer (score 0):

Check your 'Network Profile' if you're set as Public switching to Private may help.